# Jquery Dialog box- hide Address

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

How do I redirect the user to another page withing the same website?

In my case, I have a form where a user fills in some information. so, for cancellation they should have options. When a user hits that button, he/she will get a dialog box. If hits ok, they will be redirected to the index page.

I don't want the user to see the address of my website. Why? I developed an android app where I managed to hide the address bar of my browser.

I'm using Jquery Mobile in this case. I have already written something like this in JavaScript but I still have the problem with the address showing up in the dialog box. I was told I could do this in Jquery, so I started to learn it. Cancel button:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <button data-theme="b" id="canc" onclick="cancelMe()"   dataicon="delete">cancel</button>
</div>
```

Here's my JavaScript:

```
<script>
      function cancelMe() {
  var answer = confirm("Are You sure?")
  if (answer){
  alert("No information saved!")
    window.location = "http://www.stackovrflow.com";
    }
    else{
    alert("You may hit save to submit information")
    }
    }
</script>
```

And I started Jquery here, but I'm not sure yet:

```
$(document).delegate('#canc', 'click', function() {
  $(this).simpledialog({
   'mode' : 'string',
   'prompt' : 'Are you sure?',
   'buttons' : {
   'OK': {
     click: function () {

     // Here's the issue
      window.location.href = 'http://www.stackovrflow.com';
    }
  },
  'Cancel': {
    click: function () { },
    icon: "delete",
    theme: "b"
    }
   }
  })
})
```

I know this could be done in Ajax somehow, but don't know how? I might have to know a little about Ajax. If you know any other way of doing this, please enlighten me.

Thanks,
YahyaOtaif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot change the title of the confirm dialog. the only way is simulate the confirmation box. this is a good article [how to do it using jQuery](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/)

Comment: can sliding back work for me here ? all i need is to go two steps back; any idea ?

Comment: for that use `window.history.go(-2)`. _and why reduce the vote again?_

Comment: but this didn't solve my problem, it's almost the same as using window.location = "index.php";

Comment: your problem is **address showing up in the dialog box** for that my solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery Mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/#/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html

I think its better, since you're already using it.